# how to set value after sumit or button click

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, jsp

```
<%@ page language="java" contenttype="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1" pageencoding="ISO-8859-1" %>

<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
    <title>Insert title here</title>
</head>
<body>
    <form method="post" action="index.jsp" name="productForm">
    <select name="colour" onchange="document.productForm.submit();">
        <option value="dropdown">Pls select one
        <option value="apple">Apple
        <option value="oragne">Orange
        <option value="grapes">Grapes
    </select>
    <input type="hidden" name="dropdown" id="dropdown">
    <input type="submit" value="click" name="dropdown" id="dropdown">
    <form>
    <%
            String colour = request.getParameter("colour");
            out.println(colour);
    %>
</body>
</html>
```

please check my code i  i have take drop down when i select apple or orange pr grapes any of one and Submit it on Button click or on-change selection Then value pass But section value set to Select option while i have to set it it what ever i set Before submit E.g If we select orange then after submit it shout set value to Drop down and value pass also please help me am Able to pass value But unable to set value in Drop down after Submit.

Comment: I tried editing this, but it's too hard (and too early) to decypher it.

Answer (score 0):

Selecting Dropdown by text

working Demo http://jsfiddle.net/cse_tushar/L6p2u/

## **js**

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var textToFind = 'Orange';
    var dd = document.getElementById('colour');
    for (var i = 0; i < dd.options.length; i++) {
        if (dd.options[i].text === textToFind) {
            dd.selectedIndex = i;
            break;
        }
    }
});
```

Selecting Dropdown by value

working Demo http://jsfiddle.net/cse_tushar/L6p2u/1/

## **js**

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var valueToFind = 'oragne';
    var dd = document.getElementById('colour');
    for (var i = 0; i < dd.options.length; i++) {
        if (dd.options[i].value === valueToFind) {
            dd.selectedIndex = i;
            break;
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: set var textToFind = request.getParameter("colour");